# Populate select elements dynamically from json data file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, combobox

I'am trying to create search box for state districts and villages , but I'am enable to fetch data into combobox.

I have tried so many other way to get data into select boxes they doesn't work. Below is the code I've so far:

HTML:

```html
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="state_id" id="state_id" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">-- Select state --</option>


  </select>
</div>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="district_id" id="district_id" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">-- Select district --</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="village_id" id="village_id" tabindex="3">
    <option value="">-- Select village --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

function loadlist(selobj, url) {
  $(selobj).empty();
  $(selobj).append('<option value="0">--Select Category--</option>')
  $(selobj).append(
    $.map(jsonList, function(el, i) {
      return $('<option>').val(el.slno).text(el.state)
    }));
}
loadlist($('select#state_id').get(0), jsonList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (Check the revision history for a shorter version which made use of [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)):

The comments should help you get an idea. check https://api.jquery.com/ for detailed information regarding the jQuery methods used.

```
$(function() {
  insert($('#state_id'), plucker(records, 'state'));
  //------------------------^ grabs unique states
  //--^ populate state list on DOM ready
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var category = this.id.split('_id')[0];
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    switch (category) {
      case 'state':
        {
          insert($('#district_id'), plucker(filter(records, 'state', value),'district'));
          //-^ insert plucked results to DOM
          //------------------------^ plucks districts from filter results
          //--------------------------------^ filters districts belonging to selected state
          break;
        }
      case 'district':
        {
          insert($('#village_id'), plucker(filter(records, 'district', value),'village'));
          break;
        }
    }
  });

   function plucker(arr, prop) {
   // grabs unique items from the required property such as state,  district etc from the results
    return $.map(arr, function(item) {
      return item[prop]
    }).filter(function(item, i, arr) {
       return arr.indexOf(item) == i;
    });
  }

  function filter(arr, key, value) { 
    // filters the records matching users selection
    return  $.grep(arr, function(item) {
         return item[key] == value;
    });
  }

  function insert(elm, arr) { // inserts the results into DOM
    elm.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
    $.each(arr, function(i,item) {
      elm.append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text: item
      }));
    });
  }
});
```

```js
var records = [{
  "slno": "1",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "constituency": "Parbhani",
  "mp": "Shri Sanjay Haribhau Jadhav",
  "district": "Parbhani",
  "block": "Jintur",
  "village": "Kehal",
  "latitude": "77.7",
  "longitude": "19.33"
}, {
  "slno": "2",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "constituency": "Shirur",
  "mp": "Shri Shivaji Adhalrao Patil",
  "district": "Pune",
  "block": "Shirur",
  "village": "Karandi",
  "latitude": "77.7",
  "longitude": "19.33"
}, {
  "slno": "3",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "constituency": "Amravati",
  "mp": "Shri Anandrao Vithoba Adsul",
  "district": "Amravati",
  "block": "Amravati",
  "village": "Yavli Shahid",
  "latitude": "77.7",
  "longitude": "19.33"
}]
$(function() {
  insert($('#state_id'), plucker(records, 'state'));
  //------^ populate states list on DOM ready

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var category = this.id.split('_id')[0];
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    switch (category) {
      case 'state':
        {
          insert($('#district_id'), plucker(filter(records, 'state', value), 'district'));
          break;
        }
      case 'district':
        {
          insert($('#village_id'), plucker(filter(records, 'district', value), 'village'));
          break;
        }
    }
  });


  function plucker(arr, prop) {
    // grabs unique items from the required property such as state, district etc from the results
    return $.map(arr, function(item) {
      return item[prop]
    }).filter(function(item, i, arr) {
      return arr.indexOf(item) == i;
    });
  }

  function filter(arr, key, value) {
    // filters the records matching users selection
    return $.grep(arr, function(item, i) {
      return item[key] === value;
    });
  }

  function insert(elm, arr) {
    // inserts the results into DOM
    elm.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
    $.each(arr, function(i, item) {
      elm.append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text: item
      }));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="state_id" id="state_id" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">-- Select state --</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="district_id" id="district_id" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">-- Select district --</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="village_id" id="village_id" tabindex="3">
    <option value="">-- Select village --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you ..but i never use underscorejs . :) i'm very in new in js

Comment: @aditiparmar you mean like this https://plnkr.co/edit/wRFLX0RkJqG27aUDRVJG?p=preview ..?

Comment: @aditiparmar in that example I'm using `$.getJSON()` and loading datafrom  a `.json` file... You can use `$.ajax()` in similar way if you want to fetch data from some other end point apart from a `.json` file...

Comment: ...If you mean the data will be in another `.js` file, all you have to do is link it with a `<script>` tag before this code and make sure records variable point to the actual data list like `var records = jsonList.listval`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function createOptiolist(list, name) {
  var state = list.map(function(obj) {
    return obj[name];
  });
  return state = state.filter(function(v, i) {
    return state.indexOf(v) == i;
  });

}

var state = createOptiolist(jsonList.listval, "state");
$.each(state, function(i, el) {
  $('#state_id').append('<option value="' + el + '">' + el + '</option>');
});
$('#state_id').on('change', function() {
  var state = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $('#district_id').empty();
  $.each(jsonList.listval, function(i, el) {
    if (el.state == state) {
      $('#district_id').append('<option value="' + el.district + '">' + el.district + '</option>');
    }
  })
});
$('#district_id').on('change', function() {
  var district = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $('#village_id').empty();
  $.each(jsonList.listval, function(i, el) {
    if (el.district == district) {
      $('#village_id').append('<option value="' + el.slno + '">' + el.village + '</option>');
    }
  })
});
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/VxVsEygzloIuhbUyubvy?p=preview)

[DEMO with ajax](https://plnkr.co/edit/VxVsEygzloIuhbUyubvy?p=preview)

Comment: But if i tried this one as you see in ur result there is multiple number of maharashtra start showing. i wanted in my result when we select maharashtra then its should show district within it

Comment: you want a multiple layered select?

Comment: yah that means it should select the corresponding result like when we select maharashtra then in the  next drop down  there will we options like parbhani ,pune, amravati and in third one villages will be there of that particular district

Comment: here's only one doubt i have if wanted to fetch json file through  url ..where i can enter that getson code

Comment: if you mean using ajax then you put the code in the success function of the ajax

Comment: okay but before creating the variable of state we can it call it through  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jlist.js',
        success: function(data
         }
    like this

Comment: you do it like this if you need the data from a json file `$.ajax({ type: 'get', url: 'path_to.json', success: function(jsonList){//my code here}});`

Comment: @aditiparmar see the demo above

Comment: you need to reference the js file in the html file http://plnkr.co/edit/skyxHnBpyf5TohdgoAlG?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In your above code you have made the following mistake,

1.Extra close bracket

```
    $.map(jsonList, function (el, i) {
        return $('<option>').val(el.slno).text(el.state)
    }));
```

Update it as

```
    $.map(jsonList, function (el, i) {
        return $('<option>').val(el.slno).text(el.state)
    });
```

2. The looping of json object

   ```
   $.map(jsonList.listval, function (el, i) {
           $('#state_id').append('<option value="'+el.slno+'" attState="'+el.state+'">'+el.state+'</option>');            
   });
   ```

To avoid multiple times the same state repetition, before inserting the option you need to check if the entry is already exist in option if not exist then add it to the select, for this I have introduced a new option attribute "attState". Please look in to the code you will understand what I have done..

```
$.map(jsonList.listval, function (el, i) {
    if ($("#yourSelect option[attState='" + el.state + "']").length == 0) {
        $('#yourSelect').append('<option value="' + el.slno + '" attState="' + el.state + '">' + el.state + '</option>');
    }
});
```

For reference [refer](https://jsfiddle.net/Karthik7724/ybv7Lpuh)

Answer (score 0):

Try this plz

**HTML**

```
<div class="dummy__item">
    <select name="state_id" id="state_id" tabindex="1">
        <option value="">-- Select state --</option>


    </select>
</div>

<div class="dummy__item">
    <select name="district_id" id="district_id" tabindex="2">
        <option value="">-- Select district --</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="dummy__item">
    <select name="village_id" id="village_id" tabindex="3">
        <option value="">-- Select village --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            // JSON list
var jsonList = {"listval" : [
{
    "slno": "1",
    "state": "Maharashtra",
    "constituency": "Parbhani",
    "mp": "Shri Sanjay Haribhau Jadhav",
    "district": "Parbhani",
    "block": "Jintur",
    "village": "Kehal",
    "latitude": "77.7",
    "longitude": "19.33"
},
{
    "slno": "2",
    "state": "Maharashtra",
    "constituency": "Shirur",
    "mp": "Shri Shivaji Adhalrao Patil",
    "district": "Pune",
    "block": "Shirur",
    "village": "Karandi",
    "latitude": "77.7",
    "longitude": "19.33"
},
{
    "slno": "3",
    "state": "TEXAS",
    "constituency": "XYZ",
    "mp": "Shri ABC",
    "district": "dist1",
    "block": "block1",
    "village": "Yavli Shahid",
    "latitude": "77.7",
    "longitude": "19.33"
},
{
    "slno": "4",
    "state": "Maharashtra",
    "constituency": "Amravati",
    "mp": "Shri Anandrao Vithoba Adsul",
    "district": "Amravati",
    "block": "Amravati",
    "village": "Yavli Shahid",
    "latitude": "77.7",
    "longitude": "19.33"
}]}
// JSON LIST


function loadlist(selobj, url) {
    var categories = [];
    $(selobj).empty();
    $(selobj).append('<option value="0">--Select Category--</option>')
    $(selobj).append(

    $.map(jsonList.listval, function (el, i) {

     if ($.inArray(el.state, categories)==-1) {

    categories.push(el.state);
        return $('<option>').val(el.slno).text(el.state);
        console.log($(el.state));}
    }));
}


 loadlist($('#state_id').get(0), jsonList);


});
```

Comment: I have added TEXAS so that we can know the difference.. you can see Maharastra is loaded only once