# How to get questions based on category, subcategory, sub subcategory etc from a JSON file for a quiz

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using js, html, CSS and JSON for making a question bank of different categories and levels of difficulty.

I have made a quiz question Bank in JSON - quizquestion.json - with options, levels of difficulty and different categories, sub categories and sub sub category. I want to select categories, subcategories,.... and level of difficulty for the quiz.

I have included the selection in HTML as follows:

```html
<label for="categories">Choose category</label>
<select name="categories" id="categories">
  <option value="GK">General Knowledge</option>
  <option value="science">Science</option>
  <option value="history">History</option>
</select> 
  
<p>
  <label for="levels">Choose difficulty level</label>
  <select name="levels" id="levels">
    <option value="easy">Easy</option>
    <option value="mod">Moderate</option>
    <option value="hard">Hard</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

I am loading the json file and assigning the questions and answers as follows. But I want to render questions of one category of one difficulty level. How do I do it?

```js
$.getJSON('quizquestion.json', function(data) {
  for(i=0;i<data.quizquestions.length;i++) { 
    qBank[i]    =new Array;
    qBank[i][0] = data.quizquestions[i].question;
    qBank[i][1] = data.quizquestions[i].option1;
    qBank[i][2] = data.quizquestions[i].option2;
    qBank[i][3] = data.quizquestions[i].option3;
    qBank[i][4] = data.quizquestions[i].option4;
  }
  renderQuestion();
})
```

Small portion of JSON file is as follows  :

```js
{ quizquestions :
  [ { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'physics', 'sub-category1': 'light', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'Which color is not part of VIBGYOR', answer: 'Brown'
    , option1: 'Violet', option2: 'Red', option3: 'Orange', option4: 'Brown'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'physics', 'sub-category1': 'energy', levels: 'moderate'
    , question: 'Which form of energy is renewable form of energy?', answer: 'solar'
    , option1: 'electric', option2: 'solar', option3: 'coal', option4: 'petroleum'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'chemistry', 'sub-category1': 'Elements', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'Gold is represented in the periodic table by which Symbol?', answer: 'Au'
    , option1: 'Go', option2: 'Au', option3: 'Ye', option4: 'ld'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'chemistry', 'sub-category1': 'Elements', levels: 'moderate'
    , question: 'Tin is represented in the periodic table by which Symbol?', answer: 'Sb'
    , option1: 'Go', option2: 'Au', option3: 'Sb', option4: 'ld'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'chemistry', 'sub-category1': 'Elements', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'Lead is represented in the periodic table by which Symbol?', answer: 'Pb'
    , option1: 'Pb', option2: 'Au', option3: 'Sb', option4: 'ld'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'worldwar', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'Where were the atom bombs dropped?', answer: 'Japan'
    , option1: 'Germany', option2: 'Poland', option3: 'Russia', option4: 'Japan'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'USA', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'When did USA become independent?', answer: '1776'
    , option1: '1774', option2: '1776', option3: '1876', option4: '1879'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'USA', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'Who was the first presidnet of USA?', answer: 'George Washington'
    , option1: 'John Adams', option2: 'Thomas Jefferson', option3: 'George Washington', option4: 'James Madison'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'USA', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'What is the capital of USA?', answer: 'Washington'
    , option1: 'New York', option2: 'Washington', option3: 'Chicago', option4: 'California'
    } 
  , { category: 'general knowledge', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'What is the capital of France?', answer: 'Paris'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Brussels', option4: 'Moscow'
    } 
  , { category: 'general knowledge', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'What is the capital of Russia?', answer: 'Moscow'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Brussels', option4: 'Moscow'
    }
  , { category: 'general knowledge', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'What is the capital of Portugal?', answer: 'Lisbon'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Lisbon', option4: 'Moscow'
    }
  ]
}
```

For example, if I want to select easy level for category-general knowledge, sub category-Europe, sub sub category - capital, how do I render the question or execute it?

Comment: You can filter your data based on category, subCategory1 and subCategory2 using filter function on your array of objects.
var result = dataset.filter(x=>x.category == 'science' && x.levels =='hard')

Answer (score 0):

For your example you can do this, for the other conditions just change the parameters.

```js
var quizquestions =
  [ { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'physics', 'sub-category1': 'light', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'Which color is not part of VIBGYOR', answer: 'Brown'
    , option1: 'Violet', option2: 'Red', option3: 'Orange', option4: 'Brown'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'physics', 'sub-category1': 'energy', levels: 'moderate'
    , question: 'Which form of energy is renewable form of energy?', answer: 'solar'
    , option1: 'electric', option2: 'solar', option3: 'coal', option4: 'petroleum'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'chemistry', 'sub-category1': 'Elements', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'Gold is represented in the periodic table by which Symbol?', answer: 'Au'
    , option1: 'Go', option2: 'Au', option3: 'Ye', option4: 'ld'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'chemistry', 'sub-category1': 'Elements', levels: 'moderate'
    , question: 'Tin is represented in the periodic table by which Symbol?', answer: 'Sb'
    , option1: 'Go', option2: 'Au', option3: 'Sb', option4: 'ld'
    } 
  , { category: 'science', 'sub-category0': 'chemistry', 'sub-category1': 'Elements', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'Lead is represented in the periodic table by which Symbol?', answer: 'Pb'
    , option1: 'Pb', option2: 'Au', option3: 'Sb', option4: 'ld'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'worldwar', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'Where were the atom bombs dropped?', answer: 'Japan'
    , option1: 'Germany', option2: 'Poland', option3: 'Russia', option4: 'Japan'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'USA', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'When did USA become independent?', answer: '1776'
    , option1: '1774', option2: '1776', option3: '1876', option4: '1879'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'USA', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'Who was the first presidnet of USA?', answer: 'George Washington'
    , option1: 'John Adams', option2: 'Thomas Jefferson', option3: 'George Washington', option4: 'James Madison'
    } 
  , { category: 'social science', 'sub-category0': 'history', 'sub-category1': 'USA', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'What is the capital of USA?', answer: 'Washington'
    , option1: 'New York', option2: 'Washington', option3: 'Chicago', option4: 'California'
    } 
  , { category: 'general knowledge', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'What is the capital of France?', answer: 'Paris'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Brussels', option4: 'Moscow'
    } 
  , { category: 'general knowledge', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'easy'
    , question: 'What is the capital of Russia?', answer: 'Moscow'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Brussels', option4: 'Moscow'
    }
  , { category: 'general knowledge', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'moderate'
    , question: 'What is the capital of Portugal?', answer: 'Lisbon'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Lisbon', option4: 'Moscow'
    } , { category: 'history', 'sub-category0': 'capital', 'sub-category1': 'Europe', levels: 'hard'
    , question: 'What is the capital of Portugal?', answer: 'Lisbon'
    , option1: 'Paris', option2: 'London', option3: 'Lisbon', option4: 'Moscow'
    }
  ];
 

function changeEvent(){
  
    var category = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    var level = document.getElementById("levels").value;
    
 
     // for easy, general knowledge, capital, Europe
    var filteredQuestions = quizquestions.filter(
    (question) =>
        question.levels == level &&
        question.category == category
        // && question["sub-category0"] == "capital"
        // && question["sub-category1"] == "Europe"
    );
    
    // print the list.
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filteredQuestions); 
}
```

```html
<label for="categories">Choose category</label>
<select name="categories" id="categories" onchange="changeEvent()">
  <option value="general knowledge">General Knowledge</option>
  <option value="science">Science</option>
  <option value="history">History</option>
</select> 
  
<p>
  <label for="levels">Choose difficulty level</label>
  <select name="levels" id="levels" onchange="changeEvent()">
    <option value="easy">Easy</option>
    <option value="moderate">Moderate</option>
    <option value="hard">Hard</option>
  </select>
</p>

<pre>
<code id="list"> 

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: The answer                                                                                                          var easy = quizquestions.filter(
(question) =>
    question.levels == "easy" &&
    question.category == "general knowledge" &&
    question["sub-category0"] == "capital" &&
    question["sub-category1"] == "Europe"
);                                                                                                                                             works well when modified in .js file. I want to make this selection through HTML file as indicated. Any suggestions?

Comment: This edited code  in my quizthrough HTML select selects the questions of choice but gives NaN for the alert(lastQuestion) with the edited code. It it was working  with the previous editing  code without the use of selection from HTML.                            const lastQuestion = question.length - 1;
alert(lastQuestion)
let runningQuestion = 0;   Can I know where Iam going wrong. I am new to coding , but want to learn. With the previous answer, the alert was not giving NaN. But with the 2nd edition, Iam getting NaN for the lastQuestion. Will be happy to implement any suggestions.

Comment: I tried to modify the choice with the following html<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="levels_id" id="levels_id" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">-- Select level --</option>
  </select>
</div> <br></br>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="category_id" id="category_id" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">-- Select category --</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dummy__item">
  <select name="branch_id" id="branch_id" tabindex="3">
    <option value="">-- Select sub category --</option>
  </select>
</div>

Comment: I have modified the js file from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449881/populate-select-elements-dynamically-from-json-data-file-using-jquery/35451195#35451195 and modified for my purpose. Dropdown is effected but dont know how to get the filtered data ie. how to get the question, options and answers for quizquestions that satisfy the dropdown options. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do your changes here and let me know and be specific for me to understand. I shared the code here that I wrote up. so edit it and let me know. Then I check. https://codepen.io/hasip-timurtas/pen/vYKZmKM

Comment: So I created a/c in codepen and the link is attached  https://codepen.io/Spirtee/pen/ZEOxELQ

Comment: I have attached the link just now in Spirtee